# Why is the set that looks like a two sided ideal not necessarily closed under addition?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring and $A \subseteq R$ be finite, say $A = \{a\}$. The set $$RaR = \{ras\:\: : r,s\in R\}$$ Why is this not necessarily closed under addition?

Take $r_1as_1$ and $r_2as_2$. Is it because the ring must be commutative in order to guarantee that we can add these two elements and still stay within $RaR$?

Even though I see why commutativity will make this possible, I'm still a bit confused because the very definition of $RaR$ includes all possible combinations of elements of the form $ras$.

Comment: The notation is a little ambiguous especially given your last sentence; you could define $RaR$ to consist either of all elements of the form $\{ ras \}$ as you've written, or you could define it to be the span of all such elements. With the second definition it is of course closed under addition by definition. Are you looking for a counterexample where the first definition isn't closed under addition?

Comment: I'm trying to answer the question of whether $Ra_1R + Ra_2R + ... + Ra_nR$ is necessarily the 2 sided ideal generated by the finite subset $A=\{a_1, ..., a_n\} \subseteq R$ and I just took a singleton to make it easier to see in my original question. I am trying to find a counterexample for sure. That would help.

Answer (score 2):

Take $R = M_n(F)$ to be the ring of $n \times n$ matrices over a field $F$, and let $a \in R$ be a matrix of rank $1 \le k < n$. Then I claim (and this is a nice exercise) that $RaR$ consists of exactly the matrices with rank $\le k$. And this set of matrices is not closed under addition: in fact their span is all of $M_n(R)$, because every matrix can be written as a sum of matrices of rank $1$.

To be really specific and minimal we can take $R = M_2(\mathbb{F}_2)$ and $a = \left[ \begin{array}{cc} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{array} \right]$.

Answer (score 2):

The difficulty is that if you are to prove it is closed under addition, and you have $r_1as_1$ and $r_2as_2$, you have to find $r_3$ and $s_3$ such that $r_1as_1+r_2as_2=r_3as_3$.

You can see that here you get stuck.

Contrast this to the case for right ideals where you have $aR:=\{ar\mid r\in R\}$ where any two elements can have the $a$ factored out to the left, so that $aR$ is clearly closed under addition.

Defining it to be finite sums of things of the form $ras$, $r,s\in R$ makes it automatically closed under addition.